# Counting internal (non-leaf) nodes in a tree starting from any node

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

Here is a tree I have. I want to calculate how many internal nodes (non-leaf nodes) starting from any node in the tree.

[image: example tree]

The function that I have now can only count all that is below A which gives 10. But I only want those before the terminal node.

- eg. for A, it should be 4 (B, C, E, H)
- eg. for E, it should be 1 (H)

How can I modify my function to do that? Note that my data is very large so a recursive function would cause a stack overflow.

```
  name employee
0   A   B
1   A   C
2   B   D
3   C   E
4   C   F
5   E   H
6   E   I
7   H   T
8   H   U
9   H   V

#collapse to dictionary
dict_a = {k: g["employee"].tolist() for k,g in em.groupby("name")}
dict_a

{'A': ['B', 'C'],
 'B': ['D'],
 'C': ['E', 'F'],
 'E': ['H', 'I'],
 'H': ['T', 'U', 'V']}
    
# recursive function to count lengths:
def total(k,connections):
    if k not in connections:
        return 0
    
    # number of direct connections plus their connections:
    return len(connections[k]) + sum(total(child_k, connections) for child_k in connections[k])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I would suggest in recursive function is :

1. Check if the parameter `k` exists in connection, else `return 1`.
2. Store the sum of each `total(ck)` in a variable inside the function, where ck is key of every child ( for loop ).
3. Check if the  `sum == dict_a[k]`, if this is the case then that node is what you want, add it to the terminal node list.

   #Terminal Nodes
   termn = []

   #recursive function to count lengths:
   def total(k):
   if k not in dict_a:
   return 1

   ```
    # Number of child nodes.
    nc = 0;
    nc += total(child_k) for child_k in dict_a[k])
    if nc == len(dict_a[k]):
        termn.append(k)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Getting interior nodes means running your traversal and only yielding nodes with at least one child.

The caller has the flexibility to turn the generator into a list and take the length if desired, or simply iterate since the function is general (a count-specific function seems unnecessarily narrow, but if you need it, it's a simple wrapper on the below function).

```
def interior_nodes_from(tree, node):
    if node in tree:
        for child in tree[node]:
            if child in tree:
                yield child
                yield from interior_nodes_from(tree, child)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tree = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
            'B': ['D'],
            'C': ['E', 'F'],
            'E': ['H', 'I'],
            'H': ['T', 'U', 'V']}
    
    for target in 'ABCDEFGH':
        interior_nodes = list(interior_nodes_from(tree, target))
        print(f'{target} => {len(interior_nodes)} children, {interior_nodes}')
```

Output:

```
A => 4 children, ['B', 'C', 'E', 'H']
B => 0 children, []
C => 2 children, ['E', 'H']
D => 0 children, []
E => 1 children, ['H']
F => 0 children, []
G => 0 children, []
H => 0 children, []
```

If your tree depth exceeds the call stack size, you can use an explicit stack instead of recursion:

```
def interior_nodes_from(tree, node):
    if node in tree:
        stack = [node]
        
        while stack:
            for child in tree[stack.pop()]:
                if child in tree:
                    yield child
                    stack.append(child)
```

Comment: thank you very much! this solves it all! i will read up about yield as it is new to me before i implement it :)

Comment: I came into a new problem. My actual data is huge and it go into a recussive error.

Comment: is there a way to do it without recursive?

Comment: Sure, added, but make sure your data doesn't have cycles (i.e. is a valid tree). Cycles would make it a directed cyclic graph which would also cause a stack overflow without a visited set to avoid re-traversing nodes.

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb, it's best not to edit your post to completely change the question. This is moving the goalpost and makes it difficult to cleanly answer your question. I rolled your post back to the original, with the caveat that the recursion error should be avoided. If you need to ask a question specific to the code provided in the answer, accept the answer and open a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Noted with many thanks!! sorry that im very new to all these at the moment.